# How to dynamically build react components once, but still give them access to parent state?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, state

I'm dynamically building React children based on an outside ordering. Unfortunately, the initial build process (represented below in the `.forEach` is very expensive:

```js
  const [amt, setAmt] = useState(0);
  const [output, setOutput] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const order = ["second", "first"];

    // In reality, this is expensive logic to properly render the child components
    order.forEach((item, index, array) => {
      if (item === "first") {
        array[index] = <First key={1} amt={amt} />;
      } else {
        array[index] = <Second key={2} amt={amt} />;
      }
    });

    setOutput(order);
  }, []); // does not work unless I pass the amt state, which I don't want :(
```

If I build the children once on load using `useEffect(()=>{expensive operation},[]);` the state doesn't get passed to the children.

If I build the order on each state change `useEffect(()=>{expensive operation},[amt]);` this works, but creates a lot of unnecessary overhead, rebuilding the children's order every time `amt` changes.

How can I dynamically include my `First` and `Second` components ONCE, but still give them access to the state vars I pass them?

Here is the full code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function First({ amt }) {
  return <div id="first">{`First: ${amt}`}</div>;
}

function Second({ amt }) {
  const dbl = amt * 2;
  return <div id="second">{`Second ${dbl}`}</div>;
}

export default function Parent() {
  const [amt, setAmt] = useState(0);
  const [output, setOutput] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const order = ["second", "first"];

    // In reality, this is expensive logic to properly render the child components
    order.forEach((item, index, array) => {
      if (item === "first") {
        array[index] = <First key={1} amt={amt} />;
      } else {
        array[index] = <Second key={2} amt={amt} />;
      }
    });

    setOutput(order);
  }, []); // does not work unless I pass the amt state, which I don't want :(

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setAmt(amt => amt + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Straight:
      <First amt={amt} />
      <Second amt={amt} />
      <br />
      Dynamic:
      {output}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-rain-hhjm4?file=/src/Parent.js

In short: I need to build my children out once, but make sure they still get the `amt` state every time it updates.

Comment: `function Second({ amt }) {
  // const dbl = amt * 2;
  return <div id="second">{`Second ${amt * 2}`}</div>;
}`
Why not use props directly if you want to change the timer dynamically from parent?

Comment: I'm not sure that change alters anything...

Comment: I would since you are directly setting the props. if not then you'll need to use useEffect in that function and then pass the value in the dependency array.